# С какой версии net стали доступны массивы с количеством элементов больше int32.maxvalue?

Tags: c#

С какой версии net этот код нормально компилируется?

```
Byte[] bytes = new Byte[Int64.MaxValue];
```

У меня на .NET 4.7 это работает.

Comment: А что тут должно не компилироваться?

Comment: вот из msdn: By default, the maximum size of an Array is 2 gigabytes (GB). In a 64-bit environment, you can avoid the size restriction by setting the enabled attribute of the gcAllowVeryLargeObjects configuration element to true in the run-time environment. However, the array will still be limited to a total of 4 billion elements, and to a maximum index of 0X7FEFFFFF in any given dimension (0X7FFFFFC7 for byte arrays and arrays of single-byte structures). Но никаких атрибутов я не выставлял. И Int64.MaxValue больше чем "4 billion"

Comment: матерь божья! 9 223 372 036 854 775 807 байт!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный код будет компилироваться в любой версии начиная с CLR2.0 и .NET 2.0 соответственно.

Ключ gcAllowVeryLargeObjects влияет на поведение в рантайме. Поскольку у тебя на машине совершенно точно нет 8 ЭБ оперативки, данный пример ты не запускал. Для того чтобы сборщик мусора мог работать с областями памяти превышающими 2 Гб, тебе действительно необходимо задать данный ключ.

Если ты работаешь с графикой, это оправдано. Если же это какое-то хранилище данных, то выделять такие объёмы памяти - очень плохая идея. Память может быть фрагментирована и при наличии 4 Гб свободной оперативки, в неё может просто не поместиться один кусок на 2 Гб, не говоря уже о больших объемах.